Use map_batches to apply custom function, that uses another column as an argument, to multiple cols in Polars LazyFrame
I'm trying to do in a Polars LazyFrame what I know how to do with Pandas.
Here I can apply a custom function to multiple columns and that function uses another column as a secondary argument.
import statsmodels.stats.proportion as ssp
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [0, 1, 0, 1],
        "b": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "nobs": [10, 20, 30, 40],
    }
)

proportion_confint_func = lambda c: ssp.proportion_confint(c, df["nobs"], method="agresti_coull")[0]

df[["a", "b"]].apply(proportion_confint_func)

    a   b
0   0.0 0.000000
1   0.0 0.015656
2   0.0 0.026639
3   0.0 0.033880

How would I do that on a Polars LazyFrame? My attempt using map_batches
from functools import partial
from scipy import stats
import polars as pl

def proportion_confint_pl(count_a, nobs_a, alpha:float=0.05, method="agresti_coull", bound="lower"):


    crit = stats.norm.isf(alpha / 2.0)
    nobs_c = nobs_a + crit**2
    q_c = (count_a + crit**2 / 2.0) / nobs_c
    std_c = ((q_c * (1.0 - q_c) / nobs_c)).sqrt()
    dist = crit * std_c

    if bound == "lower":
        ci = (q_c - dist)
    elif bound == "upper":
        ci = (q_c + dist) 
        
    return ci.clip(0, 1)

ldf = pl.LazyFrame(
    {
        "a": [0, 1, 0, 1],
        "b": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "nobs": [10, 20, 30, 40],
    }
)

proportion_confint_pl_func = partial(proportion_confint_pl, nobs_a=pl.col("nobs"))

ldf.select(pl.col(["a", "b"]).map_batches(proportion_confint_pl_func)).collect()


But it gives me object columns.
shape: (1, 2)
┌─────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ a                               ┆ b                               │
│ ---                             ┆ ---                             │
│ object                          ┆ object                          │
╞═════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│ [([(Series[a]) / ([(col("nobs"… ┆ [([(Series[b]) / ([(col("nobs"… │
└─────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘


I don't think this is specific to lazy dfs as you got the same output with an eager evaluation.

Then i tried and you can use proportion_confint_func in polars

Your function in this case just generates Expressions - so all you need to do is pass the pl.col to it.
ldf.select(proportion_confint_pl_func(pl.col("a", "b"))).collect()

shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬──────────┐
│ a   ┆ b        │
│ --- ┆ ---      │
│ f64 ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪══════════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.0      │
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.015656 │
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.026639 │
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.03388  │
└─────┴──────────┘

.pipe() can be also used which allows you to write the pl.col first.
ldf.select(pl.col("a", "b").pipe(proportion_confint_pl_func)).collect()


map_batches is for when you need to go into Python and call some external functionality - which you are not doing here.
By using it, you end up storing the actual Expr objects as values in the DataFrame.
>>> type(proportion_confint_pl_func(pl.col("a")))
# polars.expr.expr.Expr

And what you're seeing in the resulting columns is their repr.
>>> print(proportion_confint_pl_func(pl.col("a")))
# [([([(col("a")) + (dyn float: 1.920729)]) / ([(col("nobs")…

